# Is passing variables to php anonymus function without use legit?

Tags: php, syntax, anonymous-function

I just learned about php anonymous functions and found out that the following code is correct:

Example1:

```
//$mysqli = new mysqli(...)
(function($x, $y, $conn) {
  echo $x, $y; //$x and $y are not visible outside
})(786, 333, $mysqli);
```

Over the internet I have found examples like

Example2:

```
$x = 786; $y = 333;
(function($x, $y) {
  echo $x, $y;
})();
```

Or

Example3:

```
$x = 786; $y = 333;
(function() use($x, $y){
  echo $x, $y;
})();
```

I couldn't find any php documentation or code on stackoverflow which suggest example1 is correct syntax. Please tell me with official reference if example1 like syntax is allowed in php.

Answer (score 0):

The first example is effectively defining the function and then calling it with the values.  Something like...

(definition of function)(values to pass);

You can split into two parts to show how this works...

```
$fn =function($x, $y, $conn) {
  echo $x, $y; //$x and $y are not visible outside
}; 
($fn)(786, 333, $mysqli);
```

Comment: That was my gut thinking as well. its like `foo(786,333,$mysql)` where `foo` is replaced by its actual definition. I took this from my JavaScript background. Seems like it's too trivial for php.net to mention. Edit: Alos, is `($fn)(786, 333, $mysqli);` same as `$fn(786, 333, $mysqli);`?

Comment: @user31782, the brackets are sometimes needed to ensure that you are using the function properly.  In my code you don't need it (because of using a variable), if you have the full function in there - the brackets ensure that the full function is used as the function to be called.

Answer (score 0):

```
//$mysqli = new mysqli(...)
(function($x, $y, $conn) {
  echo $x, $y; //$x and $y are not visible outside
})(786, 333, $mysqli);
```

This is perfectly valid, and just follows from two things:

- The `function(...) { ... }` syntax creates and returns a `Closure` object
- A `Closure` object can be invoked directly as though it was a function name

There is no special syntax, it's just one of an infinite number of ways you can put the building blocks of PHP together.

There are lots of other combinations you can do for the same reason, e.g.:

```
class Foo
    public static function make_function() {
        return function($x, $y, $conn) {
            echo $x, $y;
        };
    }
}
(Foo::make_function())(786, 333, $mysqli);
```

But also:

```
class Foo
    public static function make_function($conn) {
        return function($x, $y) use ($conn) {
            echo $x, $y;
        };
    }
}
(Foo::make_function($conn))(786, 333, $mysqli);
```

As with your example, specifying a `use` clause doesn't make much difference *in this specific case* because we're executing the function straight away. But it allows you to "capture" a value in one place and then pass the other arguments *later*, e.g.

```
class Foo
    public static function make_function($conn) {
        return function($x, $y) use ($conn) {
            echo $x, $y;
        };
    }
}
$f = Foo::make_function($mysqli);
// later...
$f(786, 333);
```